# Multiple user access in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a product which is using Neo4J server. There are multiple users who wants to access the product which in turn is interacting with Neo4J server in backend.

Can anyone please suggest me how to provide Neo4J access to multiple users.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP Basic auth:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html

Otherwise you have to protect the access with a custom proxy